# Charset of Apache (XAMPP) Server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I run a XAMPP Apache PHP Server on my Mac and I am facing the following problem: German special characters like ä ö ü and ß are displayed with strange questiontags instead of the correct symbol. I assume a misconfiguration of the server, since the files are all saved in UTF-8 and contain

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

In the -Tag of the files.

Anyone an idea how to get rid of those � ? I thought already of the httpd.conf , but there is already something like

```
#UTF 8
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

in it. The php.ini also includes

```
default_charset = "utf-8“
```

I really dont know how to proceed and my whole page looks not as nice as it should with those strange question tags...

Thanks for your Help! 
Tim

Comment: using firefox by chance?

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say those characters are being transmitted as?

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem on my XAMPP local server and none of those things worked for me. The problem was in the transfer of data between mySQL (where all my foreign language looked good) and the server (where everything seemed good too). I was just missing this one statement in my.ini
"character_set_server=utf8"
which seems to affect data communication beetween server and mySQL
DON't change any other UTF-8 statements at the same time!

Comment: Brother you saved me! I was having the same error when using a database with mostly cyrillic text and the characters were showing up as ?.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem after updating XAMPP. 
I am using an other charset to display all kinds of characters used in countries like Holland, Germany, Norway, Sweden en Denmark. So my HTML contains:

Changing the default-charset into "windows-1252" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you type these characters inside the source file? In this case, which encoding was the source file saved in?

With that meta tag "Content-Type" you are telling the browser to interpret the page as UTF-8 (*despite whatever other value the server is returning*). 
However, if you are saving the file in a different encoding that UTF-8, then it is displayed in the wrong way.

My suggestion is to check with your editor which encoding it is using, and tell it to use UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Sure, I save them in utf-8 format, thats not the problem. It's also the xampp startpage that shows that strange question tags

Comment: What happens if you open the page with another browser? And what happens if you open the HTML page directly (using the "file:// protocol") instead of passing through XAMPP?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open "my.ini" in "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\" directory.
2. Remove comment tag '#' from following code

   ```
   init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
   collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
   character_set_server=utf8
   skip-character-set-client-handshake
   character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
   ```

It's Work for me

Comment: Finally, so this was causing all the problem. It took me more than 3 hours to solve this one. I thought it was my PHP config that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP file was in ANSI format. I changed it to UTF-8 and everything started working. I did not change any code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write your answer in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Answer (score 0):

I add to my.ini config file xampp and resolve

```
[mysqld] 

character-set-server = utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

delete this line in file mysql/bin/my.ini

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

or change utf8mb4 to uft8

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```